# Animations not working in ios playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, uianimation

This is my animation method (PreloaderView.swift)

```
public func performAction(action: PreloaderAction)
{
    let highOpacity = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
    let middleOpacity = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
    let lowOpacity = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")

    if action == .PreloaderActionNone {
        self.thirdShape.removeAllAnimations()
        self.firstShape.opacity = 0.3;
        self.secondShape.opacity = 0.5
        self.thirdShape.opacity = 1.0
    } else if action == .PreloaderActionFailure {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
            self.thirdShape.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        }) {(completed : Bool) in
            self.thirdShape.strokeColor = self.ringColor.CGColor
        }

    }

    if action == .PreloaderActionStart {

        highOpacity.fromValue = 0.0
        highOpacity.toValue = 1.0
        highOpacity.duration = animationDuration
        highOpacity.autoreverses = true
        highOpacity.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.secondShape.addAnimation(highOpacity, forKey: "highOpacity")

        middleOpacity.fromValue = 0.0
        middleOpacity.toValue = 1.0
        middleOpacity.duration = animationDuration
        middleOpacity.autoreverses = true
        middleOpacity.repeatCount = .infinity
        middleOpacity.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.33
        self.firstShape.addAnimation(middleOpacity, forKey: "middleOpacity")

        lowOpacity.fromValue = 0.0
        lowOpacity.toValue = 1.0
        lowOpacity.duration = animationDuration
        lowOpacity.autoreverses = true
        lowOpacity.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.66
        lowOpacity.repeatCount = .infinity
        self.thirdShape.addAnimation(lowOpacity, forKey: "lowOpacity")

    }
}
```

This is my playground file

[image]

and playground in project navigator

[image]

Animations work fine on device, but when I use playground animations not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Xcode 7, Swift 2**

Add

```
import XCPlayground
```

at the top of the Playground, then use

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

at the bottom of the Playground, where `view` is the view you want to render.

You also have to open the "Assistant Editor" (in the "View" menu) to see the current live view.

Also, if you're using asynchronous operations, you have to include

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

in order to use them in a Playground.

**Xcode 8, Swift 3**

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: Ah, I just noticed in your screenshot you're actually already using XCPlayground. Then the issue might be with the inline view, it should work with the Assistant Editor instead.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that I need to use the Assistent Editor.  Thank you.